# Matlab - Blockproc/tifflib failing while writing big tiff File

Tags: matlab, image-processing, io, tiff

In Matlab I use blockproc to process a big (geo) tiff file (in the order of 10Gb) containing only one band of 32bit float data.

My problem now is that blockproc, or more specific tifflib, suddenly fails to write a tile. This is independant from the inputfile, Harddrive/file location, or other parameters, such as processing, Matlab version, and even OS.

And it's usually always around the same tilenumber (#3372for linux, #3176 for Windows 10).

But blockproc runs through when using a smaller version of the large files (~around 4Gb instead of 10Gb).

This is the error message I get (Debian 64bit, Matlab 2014b):

```
Warning: The following error was caught while executing 'images.internal.TileHandle'
class destructor:
Unable to write tile #3684.
> In TileCache>TileCache.setTile at 71
  In TiffAdapter>TiffAdapter.getTileHandle at 560
  In TiffAdapter>TiffAdapter.writeRegion at 354
  In blockproc>putBlock at 879
  In blockproc>serialLoop at 459
  In blockproc at 340
  In removeEGM at 13
Warning: The following error was caught while executing 'images.internal.TileHandle'
class destructor:
Unable to write tile #3685.
> In TileCache>TileCache.setTile at 71
  In TiffAdapter>TiffAdapter.getTileHandle at 560
  In TiffAdapter>TiffAdapter.writeRegion at 354
  In blockproc>putBlock at 879
  In blockproc>serialLoop at 459
  In blockproc at 340
  In removeEGM at 13
Warning: The following error was caught while executing 'images.internal.TileHandle'
class destructor:
Unable to write tile #3686.
> In TileCache>TileCache.setTile at 71
  In TiffAdapter>TiffAdapter.getTileHandle at 560
  In TiffAdapter>TiffAdapter.writeRegion at 354
  In blockproc>putBlock at 879
  In blockproc>serialLoop at 459
  In blockproc at 340
  In removeEGM at 13
Warning: The following error was caught while executing 'images.internal.TileHandle'
class destructor:
Unable to write tile #3687.
> In TileCache>TileCache.setTile at 71
  In TiffAdapter>TiffAdapter.getTileHandle at 560
  In TiffAdapter>TiffAdapter.writeRegion at 354
  In blockproc>putBlock at 879
  In blockproc>serialLoop at 459
  In blockproc at 340
  In removeEGM at 13
Error using tifflib
Unable to write tile #3372.

Error in Tiff/writeEncodedTile (line 1602)
tifflib('writeEncodedTile',obj.FileID,tileNumber-1,varargin{:});

Error in images.internal.TiffAdapter/writeBlock (line 420)
                obj.TiffObj.writeEncodedTile(blockId, block);

Error in images.internal.TiffAdapter/writeRegion (line 377)
                        obj.writeBlock(blockId, data(ry - start(1) + 1, ...

Error in blockproc>putBlock (line 879)
dest.writeRegion(start_loc,...

Error in blockproc/serialLoop (line 459)
putBlock(options.Destination,row,col,output_block,output_size);

Error in blockproc (line 340)
    serialLoop();

Error in removeEGM (line 13)
blockproc(in_dem, [3000, 3000], my_fun, 'Destination', out_dem);
```

Comment: Are you trying to write a "big TIFF file" or a BigTIFF file? The TIFF file format has a hard limit for file size at 4GB, due to using unsigned 32 bit offsets. BigTIFF on the other hand uses 64 bit offsets, and can handle much larger files. Are you sure there is support for BigTIFF in Matlab/the TIFF library in use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @haraldKs comment, I found the solution:

Matlab can read BigTiffs without problems (imread()), and write them, but blockproc can only read BigTiffs, but not write them.

As a workaround I wrote my own imageAdapter based on this one:
https://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2013/08/07/tiff-bigtiff-and-blockproc/

Basically I only changed lines concering the tiff-tags to fit the data I have (32bit float, only one channel, no compression etc.) and then simply copied the georeferencing from the original file later over with gdal.

```
obj.TiffObject.setTag('ImageLength', obj.ImageSize(1));
obj.TiffObject.setTag('ImageWidth', obj.ImageSize(2));
obj.TiffObject.setTag('TileLength', obj.TileLength);
obj.TiffObject.setTag('TileWidth',     obj.TileWidth);
obj.TiffObject.setTag('Photometric', Tiff.Photometric.MinIsBlack);
obj.TiffObject.setTag('BitsPerSample', 32);
obj.TiffObject.setTag('SampleFormat', Tiff.SampleFormat.IEEEFP);
obj.TiffObject.setTag('SamplesPerPixel', 1);
obj.TiffObject.setTag('ResolutionUnit', Tiff.ResolutionUnit.Inch);
obj.TiffObject.setTag('Orientation', 1);
obj.TiffObject.setTag('Compression', Tiff.ResolutionUnit.None);
obj.TiffObject.setTag('PlanarConfiguration', Tiff.PlanarConfiguration.Chunky);
```